# navigation bar can't hide xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, cross-platform

this my DetailsPage

public DetailsPage(Property property)
{

```
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
     
        this.Property = property;
        this.BindingContext = this;
              }
```

and in my XAML code, I have added these lines

NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"

but can't hide the navigation bar in detailspage

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that doing this on your customized base page or just basically on the XAML works better than doing it in code where you might, unknowingly change it in the wrong place do what I do is this

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="Proj.BaseContentPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have questions

Comment: i was add NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"> but also not working

Answer (score 0):

this is my content page

```
 <ContentPage 

               
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App6.DetailsPage"     
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:pv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
         >
```

and this is my  InitializeComponent();

```
   public DetailsPage(Property property)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
       
        this.Property = property;
        this.BindingContext = this;
        //idds = property.Id.ToString();
        //idd = Property.Id.ToString();
        //alert( idd);
    }
```

but my navigation panel doesn't was hidden

Comment: for example, you want to navigate from page1 to page2, you just need to set `NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` in page 2, the navigationbar in page2 will be hidden.

Comment: iwas write   NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" in 2 page and 1 page too but don't hide

Comment: If you still have problem, you can provide one simple sample at gtihub, I will help you to test.